# Ubuntu: Unity Nux Development

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I'm trying to use the Nux library which is used by Unity. Here's a link to some code [samples](http://inalogic.com/nux-sample-programs/) I found.

From my understanding, all that Nux needs to create a UI is an OpenGL context, which is great because it allows for the program to run on many devices. I'm trying to use the Nux library without Unity for building my own applications. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Does anyone know how I would go about building my own application? Any more documentation and tutorials other than the ones provided in the link?

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu's Unity shell or the Unity3D game engine?

Comment: Nux is a toolkit developed inside ubuntu for unity DE, It is not yet available for other programs